# What is the correct flag for contests?

Tags: discussion

There are questions for cheating on contests, challenges, exams, and homework:

*[Problem when using scanf and printf for simple on a simple hackerrank challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376855/problem-when-using-scanf-and-printf-for-simple-on-a-simple-hackerrank-challenge)* 
*[Getting a segmentation fault while submitting the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382691/getting-segmentation-fault-while-submitting-the-solution)*

What is the correct flag question that in fact are abusing Stack Overflow? I feel like the provided options do not fit such situations. The contest is exactly the opposite of asking a question; it is about ability to give an answer.

Comment: The fact that it's for a contest isn't really important as far as Stack Overflow is concerned. If it's low-effort or otherwise bad as a question on its own, use the same flag you'd use if it wasn't for a contest.

Comment: What is exacly the correct flag?

Comment: You seem fixated on which flag to use, but maybe you ought to read that duplicate post (linked above) first.

Comment: Like I said, treat it exactly the same way as if it were a normal question. If nothing is wrong with it aside from being from a contest, don't flag it. If it's unclear, flag it as needs details/clarity, etc.

Comment: How can I treat an illegal question as legal and pretend that it is ok?

Comment: @armagedescu "Illegal" and "against the rules of the contest" are two very different things. If you personally don't like it you can downvote it or just ignore it, but it's not Stack Overflow's job to enforce the rules of an unaffiliated web site.

Comment: It is as illegal, but does not have yet regulations, a loophole. The regulations are developing but little slower than internet, a good example GDPR.

Answer (score 5):

**Who cares** if they're cheating in a contest??

We don't close questions because of dubious ethical clauses; we close questions because they're poor or incomplete or unclear or otherwise off-topic.  It's the same philosophy we leverage for homework questions, in that we can answer the question as stated, but we are not responsible for a student's academic honesty.

Comment: Meh.  Sometimes I close them anyway.  Ohhh, that better be the mother of all stellar homework questions.  If it's clearly a copy/paste, I reflexively close it, with whatever close hammer I can find.

Comment: And if it's someone who wants help breaking into Citibank, well... I have better things to do with my time.  Where's that close hammer?

Comment: I care. How can I treat an illegal question as legal and pretend that it is ok?

Comment: @armagedescu: Since you still appear to have not read that duplicate post, I'll summarize: *"Because we can't police the entire world."*  We already have our hands full with Stack Overflow; we don't have any jurisdiction for contests or any other legal matters.

Comment: Of course, nothing prevents you from exercising your own moral judgement and denying an OP the illegal answer they're looking for.  I'd love to see more of that kind of restraint.

Comment: @armagedescu:  I'm not the police.  I refuse to enforce laws that I have no jurisdiction to.  I don't get paid *enough* to care.

Comment: @armagedescu can you please clarify what you mean "illegal question"? Stack Overflow generally governed by US laws and its own CoC. Neither of those say "asking questions that may be used to answer HackerRank problem is not allowed".

Comment: Illegal means exactly one thing. Graduating by cheating. It is very illegal. Supposing that's a doctor who is going to cure you after becoming doctor by scam. It is intolerable even there is not yet an explicit regulation

Comment: Surely there are no universities awarding degrees based on the results of some online coding competition. Therefore, this isn't illegal by any statute. It violates the rules set out by the competition, namely that you aren't allowed to get outside help, but it is not Stack Overflow's responsibility to enforce the policies of third parties.

Comment: It's immoral, rather than illegal.  I tend to follow the standards of morality of the poster and, usually, downvote such questions and just pick some random close reason from the list.  If the poster doesn't care, why should I?

Comment: There are no universities awarding degrees for cheating. That's highly illegal and it leads to serious penalties, up to banning from further exams. It is illegal by design. Internet is not that old, that's why there is no sufficient regulation. But a good example is GDPR. The lack of regulation is just a loophole, nothing more. That's because the phenomenon did not get in attention of lawyers. But it will at some point.

Comment: The online exams provide real certification, that are really taken in consideration on the process of employment.

Comment: Lawful — This is a key difference of toxic influencers: they operate within the rules very well, both implicit and explicit ones. They use their intelligence and awareness, so they are very careful in never over-stepping the community rules in terms of abuse and mistreatment. Even more, in some cases they weaponize the existing policies for their own gain. (The Overflow #34, Links from around the web)